# How can I get my button transparent in asp .net (c#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make my button in C# (asp.net) transparent. I tried many samples from websites, but they did not make my button transparent.

If someone can help me getting my button transparent it'd be great!

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 ultimate, in the language C#.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Give your button some class like 'transparentButton'
then in your CSS file add this class:-

```
.transparentButton
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the CSS file of your button add:

```
  background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set the Color property of both buttons to transparent. 
 With this setting the buttons assume the color of their
 parent.**

```
 Button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
Button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

---

```
 Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

Property Value
Type: `System.Drawing.Color`
A `Color` representing a system-defined color.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `BackColor="transparent"` to the ASP.NET code of your button. To show it with a code example it'll look something like this:
`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hello World" BorderStyle="none" BackColor="transparent"/>`

By adding the `BorderStyle="none"` you will remove any border from the button as well. Meaning all that remains visible from your button will be the text you put into it.